# Eloquent collection sort by array passing in callback

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have a collection like this

```
$collection = [
    1 => [
        ...
    ],
    2 => [
        ...
    ],
    3 = [
        ...
    ]
];
```

And array by what i want to sort it

```
$sort =[
    3, 1, 2
];
```

I am trying to realise how i can sort my `$collection` with code like this

```
$collection->sortBy(function($unit, $id) use ($sort) {
     return ...;
})
```

But can't figure it myself, i already have working example, where i just foreach all $collection elements, and assign them some int by what i can sort "normally", but it still interesting for me if it possible to sort by another array without assigning additional keys to collection elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

```
$sort
    ->mapWithKeys(
        function($id) use ($collection) {
            return [
                $id => $collection->get('id', $id)
            ];
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean is `krsort`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

```
krsort($collection);
foreach ($collection as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is a bit confused, but collection is already sorted by keys, and i want it to sort by another array, where keys are going 3, 1, 2, not 1, 2, 3 :)

Comment: @Nerfair Have any condition you want for sort?

Comment: Just what collection would be sort by $sort array id's

Answer (score 1):

Laravel collections include a `map()` method for.doing things like this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map

It may also be worth looking at the `mapWithKeys()` method as well.

These methods allow you to pass in a collection and iterate through it  passing each iteration to a callback function defined by you.